# Cycles makes Grass look like Black Clumps

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, objects, particles

this is more of an expert advice thing than a technical error.

I'm adding a grass particle system to my scene in cycles but somehow the lighting makes the grass look black and very not-grassy.

Image in Texture View

[image]

Image in Render View

[image]

Grass Particle Model

[image]

I have shade smooth on and here are the upper particle settings

[image]

Thanks for reading, I love it when people help me with stuff like this. Lastly, here is the blend file.

[image]

Comment: before uploading blend file please use file -> external data -> pack all into file

Comment: Increase the max transparent bounces

Comment: Sorry, I packed the textures into the wrong file when I exported it, but increasing the transparent bounces to 100 bounces solved the problem.